# Exploding an Echo that is separated by commas into new lines

Tags: php, echo

I'm echoing the results a multi-select dropdown, but they appear in one line, with commas and no spaces. Users fill out a form, and select as many items as they want from the dropdown. On their profile, I want to display their selections.

```
Market Segment:<br>
,Health Systems-Large,Health Systems-Small/Medium,Community Hospitals
```

I want them to display as:

```
Market Segment:<Br>
Health Systems-Large<br>
Health Systems-Small/Medium<br>
Community Hospitals
```

My current code:

```
<?php if ($user["market_segment"] !="") { ?>
Market Segment:<br><?php echo $user["market_segment"];?> 
<?php } ?>
```

EDIT - Solution:

```
echo str_replace(",", "<br />", $user["market_segment"]);
```

Comment: `str_replace(',', '<br />', $your_string)`

Comment: First comma in start of string is typo or is correct? It cause of additional `<br>` in string.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
echo 'Market Segment:<br>';
foreach (explode(',', $user["market_segment"]) as $market_segment) {
    echo $market_segment . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to subsitute the , with a new line. So str_replace is your friend here.

```
echo str_replace(",", "<br />", $user["market_segment"]);
```

(That is if you are serving this information on a homepage, which it seems you are doing. If not you would wnat a \n instead of br tag)